# Simple case folding vs full case folding in Python regex module

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

This is the module I'm asking about: https://pypi.org/project/regex/, it's Matthew Barnett's `regex`.

In the project description page, the difference in behavior between V0 and V1 are stated as (note what's in bold):

> Old vs new behaviour
>
> In order to be compatible with the `re` module, this module has 2
>   behaviours:
>
> - Version 0 behaviour (old behaviour, compatible with the re module):
>
>   Please note that the re module’s behaviour may change over time, and
>     I’ll endeavour to match that behaviour in version 0.
>
>   - Indicated by the `VERSION0` or `V0` flag, or `(?V0)` in the pattern.
>   - Case-insensitive matches in Unicode use **simple case-folding** by
>       default.
> - Version 1 behaviour (new behaviour, possibly different from
>     the re module):
>
>   - Indicated by the `VERSION1` or `V1` flag, or `(?V1)` in the pattern.
>   - Case-insensitive matches in Unicode use **full case-folding** by default.
>
> If no version is specified, the regex module will default to `regex.DEFAULT_VERSION`.

I tried a few examples myself but didn't figure out what it does:

```py
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import regex
>>> r = regex.compile("(?V0i)и")
>>> r
regex.Regex('(?V0i)и', flags=regex.I | regex.V0)
>>> r.search("И")
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='И'>
>>> regex.search("(?V0i)é", "É")
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='É'>
>>> regex.search("(?V0i)é", "E")
>>> regex.search("(?V1i)é", "E")
```

What is the difference between simple case-folding and full case-folding? Or can you provide an example where a (case insensitive) regex matches something in V1 but not in V0?

Comment: Not tested but it probably follows [this table](ftp://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CaseFolding.txt). Full case folding may replace a few special characters by two characters, simple casefolding doesn't. Such characters are e.g. capital and small latin sharp s.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Great, it works. You can get a green tick if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows the [Unicode case folding table](ftp://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CaseFolding.txt). Excerpt:

```
# The entries in this file are in the following machine-readable format:
#
# <code>; <status>; <mapping>; # <name>
#
# The status field is:
# C: common case folding, common mappings shared by both simple and full mappings.
# F: full case folding, mappings that cause strings to grow in length. Multiple characters are separated by spaces.
# S: simple case folding, mappings to single characters where different from F.

[...]

# Usage:
#  A. To do a simple case folding, use the mappings with status C + S.
#  B. To do a full case folding, use the mappings with status C + F.
```

The folding is only different for a few special characters, examples are small and capital latin sharp s:

```
00DF; F; 0073 0073; # LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S

[...]

1E9E; F; 0073 0073; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S
1E9E; S; 00DF; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S
```