# What is the purpose of the MB_CASE_*_SIMPLE constants?

Tags: php, mbstring

According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.constants.php#migration73.constants.mbstring), the following constants have been added in PHP 7.3:

- `MB_CASE_FOLD`
- `MB_CASE_LOWER_SIMPLE`
- `MB_CASE_UPPER_SIMPLE`
- `MB_CASE_TITLE_SIMPLE`
- `MB_CASE_FOLD_SIMPLE`

I found an [example](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/issues/173) of what `MB_CASE_FOLD` does:

```php
echo mb_convert_case('ẞ', MB_CASE_FOLD, 'UTF-8'); // ss
```

However, I could not find any reference to what the `MB_CASE_*_SIMPLE` constants do.

At first glance, with simple latin1 characters, `MB_CASE_LOWER_SIMPLE` behaves just like `MB_CASE_LOWER`.

**What do the `MB_CASE_*_SIMPLE` do different from their `MB_CASE_*` counterparts?**

Comment: Can't find too much good information on it but it looks like it makes a difference in some languages/glyphs. https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pl&u=https://geek.justjoin.it/nowego-php-v7-3-opisalismy-wszystkie-34-zmiany/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can find the corresponding C implementation at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mbstring/php_unicode.c#L223

And have a look at the git [commit message](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/582a65b06f3de125887cab02d5c561168fcf94bc):

> - Full case folding is implemented, but case-insensitive mb_*   operations continue to use simple case folding. The reason is   that
>   full case folding of the haystack string may change the   position at
>   which a match occurred. This would have to be   mapped back into the
>   position in the original string.
> - mb_convert_case() exposes both the full and the simple case   mapping / folding, where full is the default. The constants   are:
>
>   - MB_CASE_LOWER (used by mb_strtolower)
>   - MB_CASE_UPPER (used by mb_strtolower)
>   - MB_CASE_TITLE
>   - MB_CASE_FOLD
>   - MB_CASE_LOWER_SIMPLE
>   - MB_CASE_UPPER_SIMPLE
>   - MB_CASE_TITLE_SIMPLE
>   - MB_CASE_FOLD_SIMPLE (used by case-insensitive operations)

So those constants with `_SIMPLE` suffix are for Unicode's **Simple Case Folding**, and those WITHOUT the suffix are for **Full Case Folding**.

And [that answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54603836/3049109) the differences on Full Case Folding vs Simple Case Folding.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some examples where it matters:

**`MB_CASE_UPPER_SIMPLE`**:

```
mb_convert_encoding("ß", MB_CASE_UPPER_SIMPLE); // "ß"
mb_convert_encoding("ß", MB_CASE_UPPER); // "SS"
```

---

**`MB_CASE_LOWER_SIMPLE`**:

```
mb_convert_encoding("İ", MB_CASE_LOWER_SIMPLE); // "i"
mb_convert_encoding("İ", MB_CASE_LOWER); // "i\xcc\x87"
```

---

**`MB_CASE_TITLE_SIMPLE`** is similar to `MB_CASE_UPPER_SIMPLE` in the same way that `MB_CASE_UPPER` is similar to `MB_CASE_TITLE`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of case-mapping:

- Simple case-mapping
- Full case-mapping

Simple case-mapping is one-to-one character mapping, for example a single character "A" is replaced with another single character "a".

Full case-mapping performs one-to-many character replacements (more precisely one-to-many code-points). In real world use-cases, it's rare to perform full case-mapping, this is because it only concerns a very small set of characters. For example in german language, the letter "ß" is strictly lowercase and should be mapped to "SS" in uppercase words.

Source: https://jawira.github.io/case-converter/case-mapping.html